# Rename Selected folder inside directory folder using python

Tags: python-3.x

i need help to create a code using python to rename specific folder inside many subfolder in side the main folder

Example:

theirs folder name fromDrawing inside many folder subfolder and need to rename it to Drawing

[main folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bbviz.png)
[sub-folders](https://i.stack.imgur.com/plgOY.png)

Comment: umm shutil.move?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To rename folder using python, you can use the os.rename functionality..

Example:

```
import os,sys
os.rename("path_to_initial_folder","same_path_with_changed_name")
```

Comment: i will try sir thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try using sys/os? I'm not good with sys and os, so I can't give you an example. (I have just never needed it really.)